# Best system for Hyperledger Fabric on Amazon Web services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I want to use an AWS VM for Blockchain development using Hyperledger Fabric. Can anyone suggest which EC2 system will be best considering minimum requirement is 4gb RAM. I want to use pay on demand, how much it might cost for 280 hours approximately?

Regards,
KD

Comment: Why is this question being down rated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [check here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) what instance type suits you. Based on the 4GB RAM requirement, minimum you'll need is t2.medium

And you can use the [AWS Monthly Calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) to check the projected monthly bills

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. I was able to get an instance and also setup my budget.